# how to extract the status of a subprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

my situation goes like this:
first, I opened a subprocess while keeping a main process, somehow like `subprocess = Process(target=func, name='MySubprocess')`

when I printed `subprocess` before `subprocess.start()`, I got info showing like this: `<Process(MySubprocess), initial>`; 
after `subrpocess.start()`, print `subprocess` and I got `<Process(MySubprocess), started>`;
after `subrpocess.join()`, I got `<Process(MySubprocess, stopped)>`.

So I am wondering now how to extract `initial`, `started` or even `stopped`.
I know it is possbiel to use `Subprocess.is_alive()` to confirm the alive status of sub process, but it will be good it I can extract a status like 'initial' or 'stopped', then I can use this to make judgement per my requirement.

thx for your time in reviewing this question and giving me answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print `subprocess`, you are printing out the string returned by the `multiprocessing.BaseProcess.__repr__` method. The status you are looking for seems to always follow the parent process id. So long as that remains true for the future, this status can be extracted using a regular expression search:

```
parent=\d+ (\w+)
```

1. `parent=` - Matches 'parent='.
2. `\d+` - Matches one or more digits
3. - Matches a single space
4. `(\w+)` - Matches one or more "word characters" in capture group 1.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qNIfnd/1)

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import re


def get_status(process):
    """
    Return the current status of the passed process instance as a string.
    """

    regex = r'parent=\d+ (\w+)'
    m = re.search(regex, process.__repr__())
    return m[1] if m else 'unknown'

def worker():
    import time
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=worker, name='my_process')
    print(get_status(p))
    p.start()
    print(get_status(p))
    p.join()
    print(get_status(p))
```

Prints:

```
initial
started
stopped
```

***But note that these descriptions could change in a future Python release.***

Therefore you are better off using the following logic:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process


def get_status(process):
    if process.is_alive():
        return 'started'
    # Either never started or has already terminated:
    return 'initial' if process.exitcode is None else 'stopped'

def worker():
    import time
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=worker, name='my_process')
    print(get_status(p))
    p.start()
    print(get_status(p))
    p.join()
    print(get_status(p))
```

Prints:

```
initial
started
stopped
```

Comment: thx for your detailed answer

Comment: since I m new to stackoverflow, when I clicked LIKE to your answer it pops a notifyication saying 'Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.' So....

Comment: To accept an answer, click the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons.